# Out of memory running Tensorflow with GPU support in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

My code works fine when running in iPython terminal, but failed with out of memory error, as below.

```
/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpuenv/bin/python -Xms1280m -Xmx4g /home/abigail/PycharmProjects/MLNN/src/test.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 1/150
2019-01-19 22:12:39.539156: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-01-19 22:12:39.588899: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-01-19 22:12:39.589541: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0845
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 1.95GiB freeMemory: 59.69MiB
2019-01-19 22:12:39.589552: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abigail/PycharmProjects/MLNN/src/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
  File "/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpuenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpuenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 199, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpuenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2697, in __call__
    if hasattr(get_session(), '_make_callable_from_options'):
  File "/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpuenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 186, in get_session
    _SESSION = tf.Session(config=config)
  File "/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpuenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1551, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpuenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 676, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: out of memory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In PyCharm, I first edited the "Help->Edit Custom VM options":

```
-Xms1280m
-Xmx4g
```

This doesn't fix the issue. Then I edited "Run->Edit Configurations->Interpreter options":

```
-Xms1280m -Xmx4g
```

It still gives the same error. My desktop Linux has enough memory (64G). How to fix this issue?

BTW, in PyCharm if I don't use GPU, it doesn't give the error.

EDIT:

```
In [5]: exit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
(tf_gpuenv) abigail@abigail-XPS-8910:~/nlp/MLMastery/DLwithPython/code/chapter_07$ nvidia-smi
Sun Jan 20 00:41:49 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 415.25       Driver Version: 415.25       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 750 Ti  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 38%   54C    P0     2W /  38W |   1707MiB /  1993MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       770      G   /usr/bin/akonadi_archivemail_agent             2MiB |
|    0       772      G   /usr/bin/akonadi_sendlater_agent               2MiB |
|    0       774      G   /usr/bin/akonadi_mailfilter_agent              2MiB |
|    0      1088      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           166MiB |
|    0      1440      G   kwin_x11                                      60MiB |
|    0      1446      G   /usr/bin/krunner                               1MiB |
|    0      1449      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                          60MiB |
|    0      1665      G   ...quest-channel-token=3687002912233960986   137MiB |
|    0     20728      C   ...ail/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpuenv/bin/python  1255MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The big hint I can see there - in your error is that most of (pretty much all) of the GPU memory is already used up.  When I check the same on my Tensorflow example program running a GPU, I see:
2019-01-20 16:38:00.550256: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1392] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.607
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 9.10GiB
 You need way more memory than 59MB.  
Check what is using up all your memory and reallocate accordingly

Comment: But as you can see, I already passed "python -Xms1280m -Xmx4g" to increase the memory available to the interpreter.

Comment: @SteveCarter, my desktop has 64G memory. Did you configure something to get the 11GB totalMemory? In my case, the total memory shown here is 1.95GiB. Are you developing in PyCharm?

Comment: You need to consider the memory of the GPU which in this case is only around 2G.  Your settings are configuring desktop memory, not GPU memory.  What platform are you running on?  Is it some sort of Linux?  Can you provide the output of running 'nvidid-smi' on the command line if it is Linux?  Yes, I develop in pycharm, but I have not needed to allocate the memory in the way that you have historically.

Comment: 2GB is not much GPU RAM, the model probably requires more than what you have. You seem to think its a PyCharm problem, but its not.

Answer (score 9):

To wrap up our conversation as per the comments, I'm do not believe that you can allocate GPU memory or desktop memory to the GPU - not in the way that you are trying to.  When you have a single GPU, Tensorflow-GPU in most cases will allocate around 95% of the available memory to the task it runs.  In your case, Something is already consuming all of the available GPU memory which is the primary reason your program does not run.  You need to review the memory usage of your GPU and free up some memory (I can't help but to think you already have another instance python  using Tensorflow GPU running in the background or some other intensive GPU program).  In Linux the command `nvidia-smi` on the command line will tell you what uses your GPU
here is an example

```
Sun Jan 20 18:23:35 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 32%   63C    P2    69W / 163W |   3823MiB /  4035MiB |     40%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3019      C   ...e/scarter/anaconda3/envs/tf1/bin/python  3812MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see in my case, that my card on my server has 4035MB or RAM, 3823MB is being used.  Further more, review GPU process at the bottom.  Process PID 3019 consumes 3812MB of the available 4035MB on the card.  If We wanted to run another python script using tensorflow, I have 2 main choices, I can either install a second GPU and run on the second GPU or if no GPU is available, then run on the CPU.  Someone more expert than me may say that you could allocate just half the memory to each task, but 2Gig of memory is already pretty low for tensorflow training.  Typically cards with much more memeory (6 gig +) is recommended for that task.
In closing, find out what is consuming all of your Video cards memory and end that task.  I believe it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I am running on Kubuntu, see my edition above. Why does  only 1 process use the GPU memory in your case, but in my case quite a few processes are using the GPU memory? In TensorFlow GPU, models only use GPU's memory? What about other RAM? My computer has a total of 64G RAM. Are they almost not used?

Comment: Yes, in Tensorflow-GPU, models only use GPU memory.  If you want to use your desktop memory, then you would not use GPU support for the model.  Keep in mind that the CPU will be the bottleneck if you do your training on the CPU, not the memory.  The main reason for using your GPU is because it is much faster than CPU's in most situations.    In my case, I run Ubuntu server 16.04 and I have no graphical interface so there is only 1 process running on the GPU which is a Tensorflow program I am developing.

Comment: I see in your update that you have one PID 20728 using most of your GPU's resources.  This is your program already running in the background.  If you were to end that program, then resources would be available for the one you are trying to run.  In your case, if you are trying to run 2 training scripts on the same GPU, this is not going to be possible with the current memory allocation.

Comment: The PID 20728 is the process I am running. Somehow it has not out of memory anymore, but very very slow. I am testing CPU to train the same model. It may be much faster in this case.

Comment: You have a only 4G gpu, how fast is it in your case? Did you compare it with CPU training?

Comment: Is was a GTX970, it was okay for training - still faster than my 4Ghz CPU, 2 of them was better again.  Now, I keep that one GTX970GPU for training & testing of models that I don't care as much about.  When I have something I really need to get done, I use my main PC with twin 1080ti cards.  They have 11gig each.  Its important to note that you can also run out of memory if your config is wrong.  Say you double your memory, then you can train larger of batches of data because more can be loaded into memory.  If you get an out of memory error, reducing the batch size can help to resolve that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186993/discussion-between-steve-carter-and-ling).

Comment: Great answer. nvidia-smi showed me that I had consumed the entire GPU memory in a running Jupyter notebook.